# Wheezy: how to actually blacklist ehci_hcd?

Tags: debian, kernel-modules

I'm installing wheezy on a Thinkpad T41. Those are known to have USB2 related problems, which can be avoided by not loading ehci_hcd.

But I can't figure out how to actually prevent ehci_hcd to get loaded. Here is what I've tried:

```
echo blacklist ehci_hcd > /etc/modprobe.d/ehci_hcd.conf
depmod -a
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

...but ehci_hcd is still loaded. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the issue of module dependencies that make blacklisting a module like that difficult, I would suggest the route of recompiling your kernel with that subsystem explicitly not built.

As you mention you are running Debian Wheezy, [this guide](http://linuxg.net/compile-kernel-3-9-on-debian-wheezy/) is a good primer on building a kernel the "debian way".  I generally advocate using the latest stable kernel [3.12.6 at the time of writing](https://www.kernel.org/) but using the kernel sources packaged with debian is perfectly fine as well (e.g. the package `linux-source` or `linux-source-3.2` will fetch sources with any debian patches applied).

The important part of this answer that deviates from the linked guide is at the "Do this tweaks"(sic) instruction in the guide.

The lines given in the guide are

```
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r`>.config
$ make oldconfig
```

The first line will work if you are using a kernel build the "debian way".  If you happened to be running a non-debian kernel, the command `zcat /proc/config.gz > .config` will most likely work.  The purpose of this is to start with the configuration of the currently running kernel.  The second line of the above commands is useful if you are building a kernel that is not the same version as the one running.  It will prompt you for any configuration options not present in your running kernel, and you are safe to just accept the defaults when prompted.

Now we get to the step that isn't in the guide -- modifying the configuration.  You can launch configuration with

```
make menuconfig
```

for a terminal based config, or

```
make xconfig
```

for a graphical config.  To turn off ehci, you'll navigate to *Device drivers -> USB support -> EHCI HCD*

You'll most likely see:

```
<M>     EHCI ECD (USB 2.0 Support)
```

When this option is highlighted, hit <kbd>n</kbd>, which will turn the line into:

```
< >     EHCI ECD (USB 2.0 Support)
```

Now exit from each menu until you are prompted to save your configuration and select to save it.  From here you can follow the rest of the guide, which will build your kernel and package it into a .deb, which you can install.  When you boot this kernel there will be no ehci support built into the kernel and no ehci module to load.

Although it is a point of preference, I advocate tailoring your kernel to your machine.  Once initially configured, the `make oldconfig` will make your configuration easily portable to new kernel releases.

Comment: You might want to explain to the OP how to do this or at the very least direct him to some directions. Most ppl are probably not familiar with how to do this.

Comment: @slm Post updated.

Comment: This is what I call a nice and complete explanation! Thank you very much. As I just commented to the other answer below, the system works fine with ehci_hcd.ko removed. So building a kernel without USB2 support is certainly the proper and clean way to go. I will do so, following your instructions. The question about the impossibility to blacklist ehci_hcd remains (for curiosity purposes at least), because lsmod shows no dependency on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules blacklisting a module in `/etc/modprobe.d` will only help if no other non-blacklisted module depends on it:

> The blacklist command will blacklist a module so that it will not be loaded automatically, but the module may be loaded if another non-blacklisted module depends on it or if it is loaded manually.
>
> However, there is a workaround for this behaviour; the install command instructs modprobe to run a custom command instead of inserting the module in the kernel as normal, so you can force the module to always fail loading with a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` containing

```
install ehci_hcd /bin/false
```

This should blacklist that module and any other that depends on it.

**BEWARE**: This may break your system if you actually need a module that your blacklisted one depends on! Make sure you have a life-disk at hand!

Comment: That's a fine suggestion! What is strange is that according to lsmod, no other module depends on ehci_hcd ("used by" is empty). I will try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I tried. The "install ehci_hcd /bin/false" trick works, but too well: it prevents anything usb related to get loaded. Eg, even manually, it is impossible to load ohci_hcd or uhci_hcd. So, I tried a dirty hack. I removed ehci_hcd.ko from my kernel's modules dir. Rebuilt init etc, and... it works perfectly! USB works, in 1.1 mode, which was expected.